# Angular 2 add value to ngClass with interpolation

Tags: angular, ng-class

Lets say I have some objects in an array (lets call the array "items") like `{ title: "Title", value: true }` and I use ngFor to display them like:

`<h1 *ngFor="let item of items">{{ item.title }}</h1>`

Now lets say I want to display a class on the h1 based on if item.value is true or false. 
How can I do that?

I can't add `[class.some-class]="{{ item.value }}"`. Basically, how can I get the true or false value for the current item into something like ngClass? Am I missing an obvious way to do this in Angular 2?

(Btw, I know I can do it by adding `class="{{ item.value | pipe }}"` to the h1 and piping the value and returning the correct class based on the values true and false, but it seems like there should be a better way.)

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you use `[class.some-class]`? What error did it say?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add a conditional class like this:

```
<h1 *ngFor="let item of items" 
     [class.some-class]="item.value === true">
     {{ item.title }}
</h1>
```

Remember that the `*ngFor` syntax actually expands into a `template`. In your example, it would expand into:

```
<template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="items">
    <h1 [class.some-class]="item.value === true">
       {{ item.title }}
    </h1>       
</template>
```

When you see it expanded, you can see why you're able to use the `[class.xyz]` directive with a template input variable of the `item`.

Comment: I tried that originally and it wasn't working, so I assumed I couldn't do it. Turns out I just misspelled something. Looks like I need a break. Thanks!

Comment: @user5021816-if this helped, please consider up voting and accepting the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Using ngClass for dynamic values (where dynamicValue can be @Input() inside the component):

```
<div [ngClass]="[dynamicValue]"></div>
```

Can also be used for multiple values:

```
<div [ngClass]="[dynamicValue, secondDynamicValue, thirdDynamicValue]"></div>
```

In some cases you may want to combine dynamic values with a conditioned class. This can be done like this:

```
<div [ngClass]="[dynamicValue, (isRounded ? 'rounded' : '')]"></div>
```

This will apply a dynamic value class name and will also conditionally apply the 'rounded' class in case isRounded is true.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't interpolate it. Just leave out the `{{}}`. This will interpolate it to a string. Leaving those out will give you the boolean value, which is perfectly valid for `[class.some-class]`

```
[class.some-class]="item.value"
```

Other options

You can also use object notation either inline or taken from the component, if you have a few different classes. Basically the property is the css class, and the value is the true/false

```
[ngClass]="{'some-class': item.value }"
```

Or get the object from the component

```
getClasses(value) {
  return { 'some-class': value }
}

[ngClass]="getClasses(value)"
```

**See Also**

- [Template Syntax: NgClass](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ngClass)

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate and use ngClass in h1 tag.

```
<h1 *ngFor="let item of items" [ngClass]="{'cssClass': item.value }">{{ item.title }}</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use item.value directly. Being a boolean value. 
Use:

```
[ngClass.class-you-want-add] = "item.value === true"
```

If you desire evaluate a function that returns a boolean instead a boolean value directly. For example to evaluate if value is your desired string:

```
[ngClass] = "{'class-you-want-add' : isValue("OneValue")}"
```

being:

```
isValue(val:string) {
   return this.item.value == val;
}
```