# How to pass a class name in angular from component.ts to html SVG

Tags: javascript, angular, svg

I'm using d3 to create charts and every chart has to have a unique id.

so I need to use something like:

`<svg class="{{className}}"></svg>`

className is defined in component.ts
but this isn't working

it works when I hard code the value, but when I pass in the class name in the value it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

`class="{{className}}"` is not the right way to bind data into template in Angular 2 +. And open your console to see what error did you get.

You should read Angular Document: https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass.

use `<svg [ngClass]="className"></svg>` should work for you.

Checking this: [Angular 2 add value to ngClass with interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39501484/angular-2-add-value-to-ngclass-with-interpolation) if you want to learn more with ngClass and interpolation. 
Checking this: https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data to see how to use interpolation in a correct way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately [ngClass] doesn't work with SVG. it doesn't load the image graph and also shows no error on the console.

Comment: @MinaMounir, What web browser do you use? If you required IE10+ support, you can add Polyfill to support ngClass on SVG. Did you try Google Chrome, is it working?

Comment: I tested with chrome and IE and they don't work. I wanted to mention that the SVG is generated by d3 library so I'm not sure if it should be compiled first before it's called or what. all I know is when I hard code the class name it works, when assigned dynamically it doesn't